# Have a problem with graphics after installing Ubuntu 16.10 directly

Tags: graphics, 16.10

Yesterday, I encountered the login loop error. I tried to look up what to do, but some of it just made the screen worse. Supposedly some of it was caused by having nvidia as your graphics card or something? Well, I gave up, and erased everything, and reinstalled as Ubuntu 16.10 yakkity yak. Besides being slower to start, the computer seems fine, except for one big problem. Once and a while, the graphics just give out and die? Like, if I click to open a menu of any kind, or even sometimes the internet itself, the screen becomes completely blurred with graphics where I can't see anything. When this happens, I try just pushing power and restarting, and it restarts, but it happens again always. In fact, I will be bookmarking this page as I will probably get froze again at any time. PLEASE somebody help, this is a nightmare.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Its impossible to recreate it to take a screenshot. It just happens randomly, and when it does, the entire computer freezes.

Comment: Have you installed graphics drivers? Or did you just install the OS and just use it after that?

Comment: I erased everything, went through the instructions to put 16.10 onto a 64 GB sandisk USB drive, made it into a startup disk, went through the process of installing 16.10. What do I do to install the graphics drivers?

Comment: Firstly do you have a graphics card/chip? If so you may want to try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers) to get the drivers. Post if things go wrong.

Comment: Ok, I switched from the X.Org driver to the proprietary NVIDIA driver. Will comment again if it messes up. Edit: Just tried opening the basic Search your Computer and the graphics glitched out even worse looking, but it didn't freeze. Also in additional drivers, there was a second device listed as unknown unknown that wasn't working.

Comment: @PorkyMinch 1. You should also enable the CPU microcode and 2. What is your graphics card?

Comment: My graphics card is NVIDIA C61 GeForce 6150SE nForce 430 Inspiron 531. I will now enable the processor microcode firmware for AMD CPUs from amd64-microcode. Will edit this post if it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I did it, but the messing up graphics continued. It crashed again, so I had to restart. Now stuck in login loop unable to reach desktop anymore. Will have to be posting from my laptop from now until I get out of login loop.

Comment: Bump to try and stay on the first page.

Comment: @PorkyMinch Sorry but I have to be the bearer of bad news. A reality check is in order: nForce 430 is obsolete. Nvidia has no recommendation re: Linux drivers for that chipset. Ina nutshell, it isn't compatible with any modern 3D desktop environment like Unity, KDE or Gnome. Your best chance is with Lubuntu (LXDE). Now, adding a newer graphics card (PCIe x16), even the cheapest (Nvidia) one you can find now will make a huge difference.

Comment: So there is no way to fix the login loop? So I will have to erase and reinstall 16.10, then use the startup disc creator to turn my USB into a Lubuntu (LXDE) startup disc, and try that? The graphics problem was because my graphics card can't handle opening menus? I can play youtube videos just fine.