# Ubuntu 16.10 Login Loop

Tags: login, 16.10

Just installed Ubuntu 16.10, and now I am in the login loop. I can use ctrl alt f3 to open the console, but dunno what kind of command would fix this. Can you please help me?

Comment: As I told you before, install Lubuntu instead and do not install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Ok, I will install lubuntu instead.

Comment: Hi Porky, this did it yesterday for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/760469/72216 @Zanna: Possible, but that was no solution to me yesterday. Different reasons can cause a login loop.

Comment: Advicing to choose another distro because of an error is... weird? Better solve it.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I thought the point of a canonical question was to capture all the reasons and solutions. I should read that whole post thoroughly and see what is missing...

Comment: @Zanna ah, sure, still early here, haha.

Comment: When Zanna's right, she's right: http://askubuntu.com/questions/846236/logging-in-loop-missing-xauthority-file

Comment: @JacobVlijm - The advice came from another question http://askubuntu.com/questions/845989/have-a-problem-with-graphics-after-installing-ubuntu-16-10-directly where the (obsolete) hardware was mentioned. Trying to fit a modern 3D desktop in that won't work.